# File getting corrupted when sending through TCP in android

Tags: java, android, file-io, tcp

I am sending file over TCP from one android device to other. when I tried to send a mp3 file.
It received successfully. but the file got corrupted. (I've got the exactly the same size of file in target device).
      **My receiver is**

```
input = new DataInputStream( clientSocket.getInputStream());
output =new DataOutputStream( clientSocket.getOutputStream()); 

int fileLength = input.readInt();
System.out.println("test integer recived"+fileLength);
String actualFileName = "";
    for(int i=0;i<fileLength;i++){
    actualFileName =actualFileName+input.readChar(); 
    }
Log.d(loggerTag,"file is going to be recieved"+actualFileName  );

File file =new File("/*my file location*/"+actualFileName); 
Log.d(loggerTag,"file is going to be saved at"+file.getAbsolutePath()  );
long temp = input.readLong();
byte[] rFile = new byte[ (int) temp ];
input.read( rFile );
FileProcess.makeFile(, rFile);          
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
outStream.write( rFile);
Log.d(loggerTag, "file success fully recived");
outStream.close();
```

**Sender Is**

```
s = new Socket(IP, serverPort);
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream( s.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream( s.getOutputStream()); 

String actualFileName = StringUtil.getFileName(fileName);
output.writeInt(actualFileName.length());
Log.d(loggerTag, "sending file name");
   for(int i =0;i<actualFileName.length();i++){
   output.writeChar(actualFileName.charAt(i));
   }

File file = new File(fileName);
Log.d(loggerTag, "file going to send"+fileName);

output.writeLong(file.length() );
output.write( FileProcess.getBytes( file ) );
Log.d(loggerTag, "file sending finshed");
```

---

```
public static byte[] getBytes( File path ) throws IOException {
    InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream( path );
    long length = path.length();
    byte[] file = new byte[ (int) length ];

    int offset = 0, numRead = 0;        
    while ( offset < file.length && ( numRead = inStream.read( file, offset, file.length - offset ) ) > -1 ) {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    if (offset < file.length) {
        throw new IOException( "Error: A problem occurs while fetching the file!" );
    }

    inStream.close();
    return file;
}
```

Comment: How does it get corrupted?  What changes?

Comment: file size is exactly same. but md5 differs. if I send a Mp3 song. I wont cannot be played. music player says. its corrupted. same for pdf also. But a text file received successfully and opened

Comment: Sounds like it might be an issue with binary vs ascii.  have you explored that possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your receiver you have:

```
byte[] rFile = new byte[ (int) temp ];
input.read( rFile );
```

There is no guarantee you're going to get all those bytes in one go. In fact, it's very unlikely given a large number of bytes sent over a network. The [Javadocs for read(byte[] b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29) state:

> Reads some number of bytes from the contained input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer.

You want to use the `readFully()` method instead.

```
byte[] rFile = new byte[ (int) temp ];
input.readFully(rFile);
```

This guarantees your byte array is completely filled, or you get an exception if the socket closes before you receive that many bytes.

**Edit for completeness:** Note, however, that if your length exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE` you're really hosed. Unlikely in this case but something to remember. You *can* do this without `readFully()` but you need to do so in a loop and use the returned number of bytes as the offset for subsequent calls. This means using the `int read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` read method in the loop. This is useful, for example, if you wanted to monitor progress of reading the data from the socket.

Comment: ohhh mann... You got that right..input.readFully(rFile); done the trick

Comment: I thought of creating a big byte array by passing the long. but its taking only int. how do we send big files? will it create memory  issue bcs of keeping the whole data as bytes in memory..?

Comment: That's ... a much longer question :) Understand that when reading from a socket you're only going to get a chunk of the total ... it's a stream over the network. You'd want to use a dynamic structure for a buffer that you can add to. A `List<Byte>` for example. You read to the max of your `byte[]` then append to the dynamic structure. It's unlikely, however, that'd you want all of a large file in memory. Writing to disk as you receive the data is more common, appending to the file with each read.